# appending linked list to another linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

Im a first year CS major and Im wondering if you could help me clean up the append(StringBuilder b) method in my MyStringBuilder class. Ive traced the issue to the last time I try and append back and forth between linked lists in my test driver program.Ive inserted debugging print statements at each step before these and it seems to work fine... Each string builder object should still exist independently from one another. Thanks!

```
//SAMPLE OUTPUT (what its supposed to be)  
**Testing constructor methods  
this is a string  
 another string   

Testing Append methods  
this is a string another string  
this is a string another string and another  
this is a string another string and another another string  
this is a string another string and another another string!!  
 another string different strings?  
...appending data**  

//MY CURRENT OUTPUT  
**Testing constructor methods  
this is a string  
 another string  


Testing Append methods  
this is a string another string  
this is a string another string and another  
this is a string another string and another another string  
this is a string another string different strings?  
 another string different strings?  
...appending data**
```

MY STRING BUILDER CLASS THUS FAR

```
public class MyStringBuilder
{
     private CNode firstC; //first  character node
     private CNode lastC; //last character node
     private int length; //length of mystringbuilder object

public MyStringBuilder(String s) //this one should is correct since it was given!
    {
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0) // Special case for empty String
        {                                 // or null reference
            firstC = null;
            lastC = null;
            length = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Create front node to get started
            firstC = new CNode(s.charAt(0));
            length = 1;
            CNode currNode = firstC;
            // Create remaining nodes, copying from String.  Note
            // how each new node is simply added to the end of the
            // previous one.  Trace this to see what is going on.
            for (int i = 1; i < s.length(); i++)
            {
                CNode newNode = new CNode(s.charAt(i));
                currNode.next = newNode;
                currNode = newNode;
                length++;
            }
            lastC = currNode;
        }
    }

    // Create a new MyStringBuilder initialized with the chars in array s
    public MyStringBuilder(char [] s)
    {
        if (s == null || s.length == 0) // Special case for empty char array
        {                                 // or null reference
            firstC = null;
            lastC = null;
            length = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            // Create front node to get started
            firstC = new CNode(s[0]);
            length = 1;
            CNode currNode = firstC;
            // Create remaining nodes, copying from char array.
            for (int i = 1; i < s.length; i++)
            {
                CNode newNode = new CNode(s[i]);
                currNode.next = newNode;
                currNode = newNode;
                length++;
            }
            lastC = currNode;
        }
    }


    // Create a new empty MyStringBuilder
    public MyStringBuilder()
    {
        firstC=null;
        lastC=null;
        length=0;
    }


    // Append MyStringBuilder b to the end of the current MyStringBuilder, and
    // return the current MyStringBuilder.  Be careful for special cases!
    public MyStringBuilder append(MyStringBuilder b)
    {
        if(length==0)
        {
            firstC = new CNode(b.firstC.data);
            length = 1;
            CNode currNode = b.firstC;
            for (int i = 1; i < b.length; i++)
            {
                CNode newNode = new CNode(currNode.next.data);
                currNode.next = newNode;
                currNode = newNode;
                length++;
            }
            lastC = currNode;

        }
        else{//works
            CNode currNode = lastC;

            CNode newNode = b.firstC;
            for (int i = 1; i < b.length+1; i++)
            {
                currNode.next = newNode;

                currNode = newNode;

                newNode = currNode.next;

                length++;
            }
            lastC = currNode;
        }
        return b;
    }

    // Append String s to the end of the current MyStringBuilder, and return
    // the current MyStringBuilder.  Be careful for special cases!
    public MyStringBuilder append(String s)
    {
        if (s == null ) // Special case for null ref
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("attempting to add empty string");
        }
        else // non null ref
        {
            //convert string argument to temp char array to be passed into nodes
            char [] tempCArray = s.toCharArray();
            if (isEmpty()) // if stringbuilder is empty
            {
                // Create front node to get started
                firstC = new CNode(tempCArray[0]);
                length = 1;
                CNode currNode = firstC;

                // Create remaining nodes, copying from temp char array.
                for (int i = 1; i < tempCArray.length; i++)
                {
                    CNode newNode = new CNode(tempCArray[i]);
                    currNode.next = newNode;
                    currNode = newNode;
                    length++;
                    lastC = currNode;
                }
            }
            //is stringbuilder is not empty
            else {
                CNode currNode = lastC;
                //if string builder is not empty
                // Create  nodes, copying from temp char array.
                for (int i = 0; i < tempCArray.length; i++) {
                    CNode newNode = new CNode(tempCArray[i]);
                    currNode.next = newNode;
                    currNode = newNode;
                    length++;
                    lastC = currNode;
                }

            }

        }
        return this;

    }

    // Append char array c to the end of the current MyStringBuilder, and
    // return the current MyStringBuilder.  Be careful for special cases!
    public MyStringBuilder append(char [] c)
    {
        if (c == null || c.length == 0) // Special case for empty char array
        {                                 // or null reference
            throw new NullPointerException("attempting to add empty character array");
        }
        else
        {

            if (isEmpty()) // if stringbuilder is empty
            {
                // Create front node to get started
                firstC = new CNode(c[0]);
                length = 1;
                CNode currNode = firstC;

                // Create remaining nodes, copying from char array.
                for (int i = 1; i < c.length; i++)
                {
                    CNode newNode = new CNode(c[i]);
                    currNode.next = newNode;
                    currNode = newNode;
                    length++;
                    lastC = currNode;
                }
            }
            //is stringbuilder is not empty
            else {
                CNode currNode = lastC;
                //if string builder is not empty
                // Create  nodes, copying from char array.
                for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
                    CNode newNode = new CNode(c[i]);
                    currNode.next = newNode;
                    currNode = newNode;
                    length++;
                    lastC = currNode;
                }

            }

        }
        return this;
    }

    // Append char c to the end of the current MyStringBuilder, and
    // return the current MyStringBuilder.  Be careful for special cases!
    public MyStringBuilder append(char c)
    {
        CNode newNode = new CNode(c);
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            firstC = newNode;
            lastC = newNode;
        }   //if stringbuilder object is empty
        else
        {
            CNode currNode = lastC;
            currNode.next=newNode;
            currNode = newNode;
            lastC = currNode;
        }   // if stringbuilder object is not empty
        length++;
        return this;
    }
public String toString() //!!must change to eliminate +!!
    {
        CNode currNode= firstC;
        char [] temp = new char [length];
        int counter=0;
        if (length == 0)
            return "";
        while (currNode.next !=null)
        {
            temp[counter]=currNode.data;
            currNode = currNode.next;
            counter++;
        }
        temp[counter]=currNode.data;
        String result = new String (temp);
        return result;
    }


    /** additional private methods **/
    private boolean isEmpty()
    {
        if (length<1)
            return true;
        return false;

    }   //end of isEmpty

private class CNode
    {
        private char data;
        private CNode next;

        public CNode(char c)
        {
            data = c;
            next = null;
        }

        public CNode(char c, CNode n)
        {
            data = c;
            next = n;
        }
    } // end of CNode inner class
} //end of MyStringBuilder class
```

TEST DRIVER PROGRAM ASSIG2AltTest

```
public class Assig2AltTest
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Testing constructor methods");
        MyStringBuilder b1 = new MyStringBuilder("this is a string");
        char [] c = {' ','a','n','o','t','h','e','r',' ','s','t','r','i','n','g'};
        MyStringBuilder b2 = new MyStringBuilder(c);
        MyStringBuilder b3 = new MyStringBuilder();

        System.out.println(b1);
        System.out.println(b2);
        System.out.println(b3);  // will show as an empty line

        System.out.println("\nTesting Append methods");
        b1.append(b2);
        System.out.println(b1);
        b1.append(" and another");
        System.out.println(b1);
        b1.append(c);
        System.out.println(b1);
        b1.append('!');  b1.append('!');  // char append
        b2.append(" different strings?");
        System.out.println(b1); // Testing for independence of the StringBuilders
        System.out.println(b2); // after append.  b1 should be unchanged here
        // Special case appending to empty object
        b3.append("...appending data");
        System.out.println(b3);
     }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you tutor know what/how to use a debugger?

Comment: It's a simple debugging. The code looks not complex, just debug the code line by line and observe the values in watch window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your

```
public MyStringBuilder append(MyStringBuilder b)
```

method in class `MyStringBuilder`

the else block is wrong

```
} else {// works
    CNode currNode = lastC;

    CNode newNode = b.firstC;
    for (int i = 1; i < b.length + 1; i++) {
        currNode.next = newNode;

        currNode = newNode;

        newNode = currNode.next;

        length++;
    }
    lastC = currNode;
}
```

this code does the following - the node in this now points to the node in `b`. This means that when you append into `b2` in your test `Assig2AltTest`, then you actually modify `b1` as well, because `b1` have started to point to nodes from `b2`.

You should edit your `append(MyStringBuilder b)` method like this:

```
public MyStringBuilder append(MyStringBuilder b) {
        if (length == 0) {
            firstC = new CNode(b.firstC.data);
            length = 1;
            CNode currNode = b.firstC;
            for (int i = 1; i < b.length; i++) {
                CNode newNode = new CNode(currNode.next.data);
                currNode.next = newNode;
                currNode = newNode;
                length++;
            }
            lastC = currNode;

        } else {// works
            CNode currNode = lastC;

            CNode bNode = b.firstC;
            for (int i = 1; i < b.length + 1; i++) {

                CNode newNode = new CNode(bNode.data);
                currNode.next = newNode;

                currNode = newNode;

                newNode = currNode.next;
                bNode = bNode.next;
                length++;
            }
            lastC = currNode;
        }
        return b;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much @KrasimirStoev! This is almost working except now there are 16 empty spaces in the string between each piece of the combined string when printing the toString method.  
'code'    this is a string                 
    this is a string(16 spaces) and another  
    this is a string(16 spaces)and another another string  
    this is a string(16 spaces)and another another string!!'code'

Comment: Yes, I`ll edit my answer now - You have to add 
                'bNode = bNode.next;' in the body of the for loop